# Shutdown system, wait 1 day then turn on?

Tags: server, shutdown

I'm thinking this isn't easily done.  I see things like `rtcwake` but I don't think that's quite what I want.

In my scenario I know my building won't have power on the weekend.  So, would it be possible to do something like this:

1. Machine turns off Friday at 11:59pm
2. No power on site on Saturday 9:00am
3. Site has power on Sunday 9:00am
4. System turns back on Sunday at 11:59pm

Is there any command that can be issued to do that?

Comment: Your PC may have that ability in its BIOS, Have you checked? If not, you need to have your OS power up into single user mode when power returns. then reboot at the specified time into multi user.

Comment: Thanks, I have not. I usually access this computer remotely which complicates things.

Comment: You might have some luck with rtcwake, but you need to try it to see what works on your platform. In principle, `rtcwake --mode off --date ...` should power off your machine and make it power on at the given date and reboot. Or `--mode disk` should suspend to disk and power off, then power on and resume.  In both cases you need to see what happens if you unplug the power whilst it is powered off. When you plug it back in the machine should wake but notice it should be off and switch off again. You may need a bios setting "go to previous state when power restored".